# ImportError using third-party module in web2py

Tags: python, python-2.7, web2py, importerror

I installed a third-party module on OSX using pip2.7 with the intention of using it in a web2py controller.  A test.py file containing `from [ModuleName] import *` runs with no errors.  However, when I try to import it in a web2py controller, I get this message:

```
<type 'exceptions.ImportError'>(No module named [ModuleName])
```

I believe the module is installed correctly for Python 2.7: it is in my Python site-packages folder, which shows up on sys.path, and it includes an empty __init__.py file in its subdirectory.  I have tried moving the folder around to various other directories that python recognizes, as well as uninstalling and reinstalling fresh.

What other options do I have?  I have even considered moving the contents of the third-party module into my application's modules folder directly, if that would help, but I'd like to look into more sensible solutions first.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Most likely you are using the web2py OSX binary package, which includes its own Python interpreter and therefore does not see any of the Python modules you have installed on your system. If you already have Python installed, there is no reason to use the binary package. Instead, just download the source version of web2py and run that.